# Can i use `argparse.REMAINDER` option to get all the remaining arguments in one string, preserving spaces?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a string that is representative of multiple arguments like

```
--arg1 val --arg2 val2
```

I have one option that is defined to be `argparse.REMAINDER` to read all the remaining arguments, I want to be able to have it as one string and not as a list of arguments.

Caveats: My value might contain multiple white spaces and would like to preserve the multiple white spaces in the parsed string, such as,

```
--arg1 the  longest bridge --arg2 very true
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I didn't find a way to be able to absorb remaining string as one complete string in argparse.

Supposing this code looks like this,

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--class')
parser.add_argument('--value')
parser.add_argument('--parameters', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
```

The argument string is

```
--class runner --value 3 --parameters --arg1 thread --desc the  whole world
```

I expect to see result as follows,

```
args.class = "runner"
args.value = "3"
args.parameters = "--arg1 thread --desc the  whole world"
```

Comment: It's the shell that splits the line into words, not `argparse`.  The parser just puts all the remaining elements of `sys.argv` into `args.parameters`.  Either quote the strings in the command line so the shell doesn't split them, or join them after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj I've just posted an answer about quoting in the command line, thanks for the inspiration! BTW joining after parsing wouldn't work in this case cause there might be multiple consecutive whitespace characters, which are ignored by the shell.

Comment: Just a note, `class` is a keyword, so `args.class` is invalid. You can use `getattr(args, 'class')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's the shell that splits command line arguments, so you just need to quote the `parameters` argument when you're calling the script, and you don't need `argparse.REMAINDER`. For example:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
parser.add_argument('-p')

print(sys.argv[1:])
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Call from Bash:

```sh
$ ./test.py -a 3 -p 'the  whole world'
```

Output:

```
['-a', '3', '-p', 'the  whole world']
Namespace(a='3', p='the  whole world')
```